# Can a RootViewController instantiate a storyboard?

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, storyboard, viewcontroller

I have a RootViewController which contains an array of viewControllers, which include table, view, and tabBar controllers... Some of these have nibs, some don't, (I am combining the functionality of several apps + web apps created in the past) but they are all working fine. I have one project, however, which uses storyboard. I see many questions asking about instantiating a programmatic view from storyboard, but what about the other way around? **How to add a storyboard to my programmatically implemented navigation controller?** Is this possible? If not, what's the next best workaround? Thank you for your time and consideration.

Here is my .h code for the model below:

```
 UIStoryboard *storyBoard;
UIViewController *storyboardViewController;
```

Here is my .m code which breaks where I have chevrons...

```
    self.viewControllers = [NSMutableArray arrayWithCapacity:self.apps.count];

storyBoard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"MainStoryboard_iPhone" bundle:nil];
>>>storyboardViewController = [storyBoard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"myViewCont"];
[self.viewControllers addObject:storyboardViewController];
```

Comment: This should be possible. When you say it breaks, what do you mean? If you're getting an error, post it.

Comment: "(lldb)" is the output message... no error, just breaks at that point.

Comment: I don't see anything wrong with what you've posted. How are storyBoard and storyboardViewController declared?

Comment: Well, I copied and pasted your code, and it worked fine for me. Are you sure you have a storyboard with that name in your bundle?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well aren't I a simpleton...

I did these three things:

changed:

> > > storyboardViewController = [storyBoard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"myViewCont"];

to

> > > storyboardViewController = [storyBoard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"iPhone"];

[image]

[image]

Special thanks to commenter rdelmar, who mentioned to check the bundle part of this answer.

Answer (score 1):

The 2011 WWDC video on storyboards illustrates this, near the end of the session.

Use `instantiateInitialViewController` (or, if you want to start in the middle of your storyboard, `instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:`).

Here's a sample from a current project that loads storyboards into a tab bar controller:

```
    browserStoryboard  = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"ScheduleBrowse_iPhone" bundle:nil];
    resultVC = [browserStoryboard instantiateInitialViewController];
    UINavigationController *navigationController = (UINavigationController *)resultVC;
    filterChooserVC = (FilterChooserViewController *)navigationController.topViewController;
    filterChooserVC.managedObjectContext = self.managedObjectContext;
    filterChooserVC.kindOfContent = sortMode;
    filterChooserVC.filterGroup = filterGroup;
    resultVC.tabBarItem.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"first"];
    resultVC.title = filterGroup.text;
```

Return `resultVC`. In the calling routine, create an array of the programmatically-created view controllers. Then

```
self.tabBarController = [[[UITabBarController alloc] init] autorelease];
self.tabBarController.viewControllers = viewControllers;
self.window.rootViewController = self.tabBarController;
```